# Replace slashes / for dashes - in markdown files

Tags: php, regex, sed, grep

I have ~300 markdown files held within a single Git repository. I need to change the format of all the *internal* links within these documents. Internal links are links that do not leave the repository. They look something like this:

```
Checkout the [new plugin](/developers/tools/plugin/install-the-plugin) 
guide if you're stuck. If you know what you're doing head on over to 
the [examples section](/developers/examples/plugin-tutorials) and get 
your hands dirty.
```

I need to change all the internal links so that they:

1. Don't contain `/developers/`
2. All the slashes `/` are converted to dashes `-`.

The example above should look something like this:

```
Checkout the [new plugin](tools-plugin-install-the-plugin) guide if 
you're stuck. If you know what you're doing head on over to the 
[examples section](examples-plugin-tutorials) and get your hands dirty.
```

One caveat is that I *don't* want to target images. Images look identical to links, just with an exclamation mark `!` at the start:

```
![Plugin Logo](/developers/tools/plugin/images/logo.png)
```

I've looked into things and it looks like `sed` is a way forward in terms of tools. I've managed to build the following regex that captures the links I'm looking for:

```
\]\(\/developers\/.*\)
```

This regex doesn't ignore the `![]()` image syntax annoyingly. I was able to get PHP to return the locations of each hit on each page, but then I wasn't able to do a find-and-replace on the slashes `/` within those results.

Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a php solution or sed/grep?

Comment: I'm open to pretty much any solution: `sed/grep/bash`, `php`, `python`, anything really. I just used PHP as an example since that's the language I know best.

Comment: If you have any issues with my solution please let me know. With `sed`, you might try something, but it is not as straight-forward as PCRE regarding *skipping* matches that you do not want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do it with a single PHP regex:

```
$text = preg_replace('~!\[[^][]*]\([^()]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:\G(?!\A)|(?<=]\()/developers/)([^()/]*)/(?=[^()]*\))~', '$1-', $text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kazTzk/1)

**Details**

- `!\[[^][]*]\([^()]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)` - match `!`, `[`, any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`, then a `](`, 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`, `)` and then omit the match and go on to search for the next match at the end of the current failed match
- `|` - or
- `(?:\G(?!\A)|(?<=]\()/developers/)` - end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`) or (`|`) a `/developers/` string preceded with `](`
- `([^()/]*)` - Group 1 (`$1`): any 0+ chars other than `(`, `)` and `/`
- `/` - a `/` char
- `(?=[^()]*\))` - ...that is followed with any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)`.

Comment: That's absolutely incredible, thanks for your succinct solution and clear explanation! I'll mark the answer as correct once StackOverflow lets me (~5 minutes).

Comment: That's very true. If another user provides an answer that suits the community in a better way than Wiktor's answer, I shall mark that as the answer. Until this, I'll leave this answer as the correct answer.